# Big-O runtime to determine if List contains X and F(X)

Tags: java, big-o

I am trying to understand what the Big O would be for the following method.

```
    for(Integer i : list){
        if(list.contains(-i))
            //doSomething
    }
```

I know that the contains method is O(n)  and that a for loop like that is O(n) as well.  Does that make the total for this method O(n * n)?

Comment: The comment box won't allow me to just put "Yes."

Comment: It really depends on list.contains(i), if list contains would be a kind of sorted list and contains would use some kind of a binary search. Than list.contains(i) could be O(log n). So the whole expression would be O(n * log n)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `List.contains` is O(n), then yes, the whole algorithm is O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

BUt if you use an iterator on your list, and use the hasNext method, then your total worst case running time will big O(n). Aprroximate formula will be a constant plus n, where n is the if condition. the iterator takes a constant time to return an object, unlike the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Thus, assuming m and n are two lists, then, the total running time will be n+1m+2m+...+(n-n+1)m.